# Chrome error NaCl helper process running without a sandbox

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Ubuntu 18.04

I have recently found chrome and chromium both return the following error when running from a shell (running from menu->process just exits):

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

What I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
sudo apt-get autoremove
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
#download chrome then
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
#then try again
google-chrome
#get same error as above
```

Then I tried:

```
apport-bug google-chrome --save chrome_bug_report.txt
```

and got the following dialog box:

```
Problem in google-chrome, the problem cannot be reported, this report is about a package that is not installed
```

Tried

```
strace google-chrome-stable
```

Error thrown:

```
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x4} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault
```

As final check tried running as root:

```
sudo google-chrome --no-sandbox
[0924/200911.107145:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

Note I am connecting to the machine via Xvnc

Any ideas to try?

Answer (score -2):

As a workaround you can use:

```
sudo google-chrome --no-sandbox
```

Same issue here running kali-linux-2018.4-amd64.iso via VMware Workstation 16 on a new Windows 11 laptop.

Chrome is not opening at all by selecting the Icon from favorites menu, however it does open (albeit with naCl_helper error) after entering the above command.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199031)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389745/help-me-install-older-veresion-of-firefox#comment2401146_1389745

Comment: The above command does not work for OP, as indicated in the question

Comment: Yikes, running your browser as root?